# How to format string to datetime?

Tags: c#, javascript, string, datetime, datetime-format

I have devexpress dateedit object and I send selected date to controller from clientside but i cant convert my string date value to datetime value

When I try I get this error => `string was not recognized as a valid DateTime`

my string date value => `Thu Aug 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Turkey Daylight Time)`

Convert Code =>

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

How should I do format this string ?

Comment: First of all: `zzzz` - There is no format specifier with 4 'z'. The second, are you sure what `28` is in `d` format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert date string to date and then date to ISO and send it to server. That would work.

```
var date = new Date("Thu Aug 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0300")
var sDate = date.toISOString();
```

Comment: read the question carefully.@Eren try to convert the string value to datetime.

Comment: @user3217843, I am converting the value at client side (javascript) in a format that can be parsed at server side. Even you don't need string at server, you can have  sDate as DateTime and it will be automatically assigned in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You need to "escape" unrecognized symbols with single quote:

```
var sDate =  "Thu Aug 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Turkey Daylight Time)";
var format = "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzzz '(Turkey Daylight Time)'";

DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(startDate);
```

prints:

```
8/28/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

Works well with single `d` in third group, added one just for clarity.

Single or double quotes denote *Literal string delimiter*. You can read and check more examples at this [msdn article on DateTime formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the unknown format with Regex first.

```
var sDate = @"Thu Aug 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Turkey Daylight Time)";
var sDateOnly = Regex.Replace(sDate, @"\s*(\(.*\))", m => string.Empty);
var f = @"ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss \G\M\Tzzzz";
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(sDateOnly, f, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```